# Shorter Decimal Price from 4 to 2 decimal places

Tags: magento, decimal

if you install Magento and add Products and want to add a Price Slider you see The Price looks like that 0.2000 to 200.0000 on the left navigation bar. But in Europe you need only 2 digits after the decimal point so it should look like 0,20 to 200,00 how can I change that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the actual code for the price slider is, but if you can find where it outputs the price in the code then you can use the php round function to make it 2 decimal places:

> float round ( float $val [, int $precision = 0 [, int $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ]] )

Returns the rounded value of val to specified precision (number of digits after the decimal >point). precision can also be negative or zero (default).

> echo round(1.95583, 2);  // 1.96

https://www.php.net/round